# magento redirect checkout payment to a 3rd party gateway like direcpay payment gateway

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

Actually i am working on magento version 1.5 and i have created a payment module manually.I have enable it from the magento admin panel 
i.e System>Configuration>Payment Methods and i here i can see my payment module and make it enabled -> yes,so that only this 
module will work during payment prodedure.Now during payment information while checkout  in magento frontend
when i click on Place Order button in magento frontend during payment procedure it gave me a popup message "inavlid bankid" and i stuck around here,i want to know where
is the landing page after this.Actually i am in the testing phase of magento and after that i want to redirect checkout payment to a 3rd party gateway
Can anyone tell my how it will be done~!